# Clickable countries using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have just started dabbling in Google Maps API, but I am already stuck. I am looking for a way to recreate [this](https://makeaclickablemap.com/maps) type of map with google maps. I would need to remove all labels, get a blank background (I tried using a map style, but that didn't work for me, code example below) and light up the countries as I hover over them.

Are there any tutorials that I seem to have missed in my search that could help me or can anyone point me in the right direction? :)

```
var _mapstyle = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

function create_map()
{
    _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("eyewebz-map"), 
    {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, 0), 
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        scaleControl: true, 
        mapTypeIds: ['_mapstyle']
    });

    _display.setMap(_map);
    _display.setPanel(document.getElementById("NavigationText"));
}
```

**EDIT**
This is what the map would be used for: I have traveled a bit in my life and expect to do a lot more of it. Since my first big trip, I have been keeping a blog. I have now developed a new blog and I would like to make the countries that I've been to clickable and follow a url once they have been clicked. The ideal situation would be that when I click a country, it takes me to a page where only that specific country is shown in a map with some markers (places to visit). Once you click those markers, it should show a specific post/some information.

Comment: Could the -1 voter also explain why he placed that vote? And why he voted to close?

Comment: Correct me, you are asking for both clearing the default layer and creating a layer for highlighted countries, right? Do you have country polygons? How many countries is visible at one time and is performance critical for you?

Comment: I do not have country polygons. Performance is not that critical and it would be a world view :)

Comment: Several things you should be asking yourself: 1) is google maps the right product? 2) what level of details do you need the polygons to be? 3) do you have/know how to get the polygons data? 4) what do you want to do with your map once you have the polygons drawn? All these questions are somehow related. So, think carefully, explore the various APIs and maybe give a bit more details in your question if you don't want to be led in a wrong direction.

Comment: Is there any other product you recommend? I have traveled a bit in my life and expect to do a lot more of it. Since my first big trip, I have been keeping a blog. I have now developed a new blog and I would like to make the countries that I've been to clickable and follow a url once they have been clicked. The ideal situation would be that when I click a country, it takes me to a page where only that specific country is shown in a map with some markers (places to visit). Once you click those markers, it should show a specific post.

Comment: Don't know about google maps but you can use raphaeljs. Here you can see example of world map: http://backspace.com/mapapp/javascript_world/ and also download it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like this would be ok? Copy and paste inside a HTML page body ([JSFiddler here](https://jsfiddle.net/maurospinello/ntme75sj/)).

```
<style type="text/css">
  #map-canvas {
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // the map
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // initialize the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        myOptions);

    // these are the map styles
    var styles = [
        {
          stylers: [
            { hue: "#00ffe6" },
            { saturation: -20 }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: "landscape",
          stylers: [
            { hue: "#ffff66" },
            { saturation: 100 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "road",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.land_parcel",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.locality",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.neighborhood",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.province",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "landscape.man_made",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "landscape.natural",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "poi",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "transit",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        }
      ];

    map.setOptions({styles: styles});

    // Initialize JSONP request
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?'];
    url.push('sql=');
    var query = 'SELECT name, kml_4326 FROM ' +
        '1foc3xO9DyfSIF6ofvN0kp2bxSfSeKog5FbdWdQ';
    var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
    url.push(encodedQuery);
    url.push('&callback=drawMap');
    url.push('&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ');
    script.src = url.join('');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(script);
  }

  function drawMap(data) {
    var rows = data['rows'];
    for (var i in rows) {
      if (rows[i][0] != 'Antarctica') {
        var newCoordinates = [];
        var geometries = rows[i][1]['geometries'];
        if (geometries) {
          for (var j in geometries) {
            newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
          }
        } else {
          newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
        }
        var country = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: newCoordinates,
          strokeColor: '#ff9900',
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 0.3,
          fillColor: '#ffff66',
          fillOpacity: 0,
          name: rows[i][0]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', function() {
          this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.4});
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseout', function() {
          this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0});
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'click', function() {
          alert(this.name);
        });

        country.setMap(map);
      }
    }
  }

  function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
    var newCoordinates = [];
    var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
    for (var i in coordinates) {
      newCoordinates.push(
          new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
    }
    return newCoordinates;
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

This is a modified version of this
[Fusion Tables Layer Example: Mouseover Map Styles](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles).

You should also take a look to [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#stylers).

Another thing you may be interested in is [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/). This in the case you need a polygon data source. And here an example of using it [GViz API Example: Fusion Tables Data Source](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_worldmap_linkto.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: One more question: What parameter do I change to alter the default grey background of the countries (I managed to change all the others, except that one).

Comment: Take a look at this [The Styled Map Wizard](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), that's adorable! :)

Comment: Wow that's brilliant! Thank you. It's a life saver!

Comment: Note that the URL used to download the country polygon data was deprecated and (according to the message on the site) no longer works, there is a migration guide available: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/migration_guide

Comment: @mauros this is ok, but some country not clickable like malta, Liechtenstein etc. Can you help me how to fix this? thnx

Comment: any one know how this would be done once Fusion tables is deprecated? https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417

Answer (score 4):

As the fusion tables are deprecated there is no inbuilt google solution to do this.

Here is small sample code that i made:

https://github.com/arturssmirnovs/Clickable-countries-using-Google-Maps-API

and working sample here: https://arturssmirnovs.github.io/Clickable-countries-using-Google-Maps-API/json/